# Error : Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function

Tags: return, return-value, arrow-functions, react-strictmode

Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function , this is a common problem one can  face easily while using react JSX in strict mode

> contentType = id => {

> ```
> console.log('')
>
> if (id === 'COURSE') {
>   return <div>{id}</div>
> }
> if (id === 'PROJECT') {
>   return <div>{id}</div>
> }
> ```

}

Answer (score 0):

right ans is

> contentType = id => {
> console.log('')
>
> ```
> if (id === 'COURSE') {
>   return <div>{id}</div>
> }
> if (id === 'PROJECT') {
>   return <div>{id}</div>
> }
> return ''
> ```

}

dont leave without no return at the end , at react strict mode this happen , last and default condition always goes at the end with no extra block